# Eigen Efficient Pairwise column subtraction

Tags: c++, eigen

I have a large `Eigen::MatrixXd` A, and a `std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>` c_vec.

The c_vec stores the pairs of columns I wish to subtract from one another.

I want to form a new Matrix B, whose columns are the result of subtracting each pair of columns of A.

The naive way is obviously a simple loop something like this.

```
Eigen::MatrixXd B = Eigen::MatriXd::Zero(A.rows(), c_vec.size()) ;
int counter = 0 ;
for (const auto&[c1,c2] : c_vec) {
  B.col(counter++) = A.col(c2) - A.col(c1) ;
}
```

I feel like there has to be a neater and more efficient way of achieving this? Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds pretty good to me: readable, and vectorized. Maybe there is some ways to combine std algorithms with the recently introduced [column iterators](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialSTL.html#title2).

Comment: How large is `A` and `c_vec` typically? Is the input format of `c_vec` set or are you flexible there?  In the first line you can simply write `Eigen::MatrixXd B(A.rows(), c_vec.size());` since you overwrite everything anyways.

Comment: A can be in order of 1000s of cols. Yes I am flexible of the input format c_vec.

Comment: MatrixXd is already column major so there isn't much to gain. `for (int i=0; i<A.rows(); i++) {
        B.data()[counter*A.rows() + i] = A.data()[c1*A.rows() + i] - A.data()[c2*A.rows() + i];
    }` might gain you a tiny bit.